# TypeError: path.split is not a function in React-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

[image]

Don't know what went wrong can anyone explain, I wrote register according to the documentation but it's still giving -
[image]

Please help

Comment: I'll admit that I haven't used react-hook-form, but it seems like you're passing a bare function as an unnamed prop to that Input. What is the block with `register` supposed to be?

Comment: What does it show when you do `console.log(typeof path)` inside `get.ts`? You can also try doing `console.dir(path)` to gain more information.

Answer (score 4):

You use React Hook Form v7 with wrong syntax, here is a working example:

The field name is passed as the first arg of register

```
<input
  type="text"
  {...register("FIELD_NAME", { required: required, validate: validation })}
/>
```

[React Hook Form V7 - Register API Documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register)

[React Hook Form V6 - Register API Documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#register)